# Wireless DC Motor & Linear Actuator Control

Tags: dc, wireless, dc-motor, linear, actuator

These are the 2 items that I have:

- [24V 110RPM 1Amp DC Motor](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/151111608896?var=450202244538&ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWAX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649).
- [24V 100mm Linear Actuator](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC24V-Stroke-50mm-600mm-Linear-Actuators-Linear-Motors-5mm-s-10mm-s-25mm-s-/151188163693?pt=UK_BOI_Industrial_Automation_Control_ET&var=&hash=item2333844c6d).

First Question: To run the DC Motor I am thinking of getting this [24V 2A power supply](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Output-12v-24v-DC-Power-Supply-DC-Motor-Power-Motor-Power-/151138700015?tpos=unknow&talgo=origal&ttype=price&tfrom=151111608896) in the hope that both of the items can run off it. Would this be wise? The linear actuator will only run very rarely, while the motor will be running for long periods of time.

Second Question: I want to control both of these wirelessly. I can find plenty of examples of a dual push button remote to control linear actuators via wireless, however, I want to control the speed of the DC motor via a [control dial like this](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/141108096253?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWAX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649), but am not sure how to make a wireless version. Does anyone have any recommendations please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: NO!

1) motor: 24v, 1 amp = 24 watts

2) Linear actuater: 50 watts (according to eBay link)

Total = 74 watts. 50 watts continuous (motor running) with ocassional bumps to 74 watts when the linear actuater kicks in.

Power supply: 24 v, 2 amps = 48 watts

48 < 74 so power supply is not big enough!

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea about the wireless part of the question at all please?
Also, there is a 4A version of the power supply. Do I take it that 24V x 4amp = 96 watts. So that would be sufficient?

Comment: Assuming there are no hidden power requirements, that 96 watt power supply will be sufficient. (By hidden power requirements I mean something like when some induction motors first start up they require a lot of current to get going. So it might be 24 watts normal running, but two or three or more times as much for a brief moment when first starting the motor. The power supply needs to be able to handle that. I know almost nothing about motors, so I can't tell you if the one you are looking at has this feature, but it should be in the data sheet)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your wireless question.